# How to integrate google spread sheet with salesforce using REST

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, integration, google-apps

I have some records in **Google Sheets** and I want to get them into a custom object by using **REST Api**. I am new to REST Services.

Please any one suggest me the possible workaround for my case.

Comment: You can simply do it with DataLoader by exporting the google sheet. Any specific reason to do it with REST api?

Comment: @SarojBera Thanks for your response. But as per requirement i have to do it by Programatically. Please suggest me the better solution.

Comment: Is the google sheet is public or private (user need to login with google credential to work on it)?

Comment: @SarojBera Can you please suggest a way to do so if the sheet is private (As in user needs to login). Like an add on created using apps script to upload to Salesforce every 4 hours?

Comment: Please check this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112124/how-can-i-write-data-in-google-spreadsheet-using-apex