# How can i write data in Google Spreadsheet using APEX

Tags: apex, google-apps, google-drive

I need to write Apex code to connect with Google Drive and create a Spreadsheet and write data into it.

I am done with google Drive Authentication but now i am not getting how to create Spreadsheet and what scope should i give in Auth request so that i can create/ modify Spreadsheet. Below is my code. Can anyone please help -

```
public class GoogleDriveController {
    private String code ;
    private string key = '548018328029-3l8hn2ikongosaeudp87he1r6s9rv3jhskl.apps.googleusercontent.com' ;
    private string secret = 'PF1yzvAlhlY71cmUFSSQvPoXjA' ;
    private string redirect_uri = 'https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/GoogleDrivePage' ;

    public GoogleDriveController()
    {
        code = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') ;
        System.debug('codesdd:::' + code);

        if(code != '' && code != null)
        {
            System.debug('code:::' + code);
            AccessToken() ;
        }
    }

    public PageReference DriveAuth()
    {
        PageReference pg = new PageReference(GoogleDriveAuthUri (key , redirect_uri)) ;
        return pg ;
    }

    public String GoogleDriveAuthUri(String Clientkey,String redirect_uri)
    {
        String key = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(Clientkey,'UTF-8');
        String uri = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(redirect_uri,'UTF-8');
        String authuri = '';
        authuri = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?'+
        'scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds&'+
        'state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oa2cb.example.com/myHome&'+

        'redirect_uri=' +uri+ 
        '&response_type=code&'+
        'client_id='+key+
        '&access_type=offline';       
        return authuri;
    }

    public void AccessToken()
    {
        //Getting access token from google
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
        req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String messageBody = 'code='+code+'&client_id='+key+'&client_secret='+secret+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&grant_type=authorization_code';
        req.setHeader('Content-length', String.valueOf(messageBody.length()));
        req.setBody(messageBody);
        req.setTimeout(60*1000);

        Http h = new Http();
        String resp;
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        resp = res.getBody();

        String str = resp;
        List<String> lstStr = str.split(',');
        List<String> lstStr1 = lstStr[0].split(':');
        String st = lstStr1[1].remove('"').trim();
                SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService();  
        service.setAuthSubToken(st);  
        GoogleData sheets = service.getSpreadsheets(); 
        sheets.dump();


    } }
```

Comment: Please tell me that's not *really* your secret...

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not SFDC question. Thats google spreadsheet api question. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361814/create-spreadsheet-using-google-spreadsheet-api-in-google-drive-java

Comment: @sfdc I didn't get you... Do u want Secret key?

Comment: @PramodKumar No, it's a best practice to remove any passwords/keys/certificates from code that you post publicly.

Comment: @sfdc yes you are right. Actually those are fake one.. Well you for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access token , you can upload the file on google drive using this apex code

```
    Http http = new Http();
    req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

    req.setHeader('content-type', 'text/csv');
    req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+st);

    String messageBodies = 'Last,First,Mid,Gender,Nationality,DOB,Passport No,Email,Phone';

    req.setBody(messageBodies);  
    req.setTimeout(60*1000);
    HttpResponse respp = http.send(req);
```

Help from - http://yoforce.blogspot.in/

Where st is your access token
Mark it if helpful

Answer (score 0):

No need to do this anymore google and SFDC teamed up to do the work for us.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/g-connector-for-salesforc/inpioilbljppoobbblcpbpjplkefmkep?hl=en